# How to make EditText to be hex by default Android

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, hex

I want to transfer hex data through COM port. I have Android app with EditText where I type string formatted like:

```
AB 54 09 08 D0 E0 E0 E0 E0
```

(Can be w/o spaces)

I need it to be already in hex format. So far I have to do:

```
byte[] dataToSend = new byte[] {(byte)0xAB, (byte)0x54, (byte)0x09, (byte)0x08, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xE0};
```

(I have to type it manually atm)

Is there any way to represent a string as hex by default?

Comment: Are you want convert String to byte array or byte array to String?

Comment: I want the String I input to be already in hex format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the string received from `EditText` to the following function. It will return the sting in `HEX` format.

```
public String toHex(String arg) 
{
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

**OR**

You can use this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
...
...
String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(myString.getBytes(/* charset */));
```

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html